# cant pair programmatically with BLE device

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-4.3-jelly-bean

When I connect BLE device with my **Nexus7** and **Samsung Galaxy S3** with Android 4.3 , it connects and works fine.
When I try to connect programatically, it pairs(I can see logs and changing of the state to the paired).
But when I am trying connect and work with,there are different problem such as no service discovered and so on. 
When I connect Samsung S3 with native android tools, it works, services is discovered and app works. 
On Nexus 7 doesn't work even after native connection.
Logs that cause problems(At least I think so):

```
10-31 10:24:09.219: W/bt-l2cap(10778): L2CA_EnableUpdateBleConnParams - unknown BD_ADDR e0c79d649927
10-31 10:24:09.219: E/bt-btm(10778): btm_sec_disconnected - Clearing Pending flag
10-31 10:24:09.219: E/bt-btif(10778): Unknown conn ID: 3
10-31 10:24:09.219: E/bt-btif(10778): property type:3, len:0 is invalid
10-31 10:24:09.219: E/(10778): ### ASSERT : external/bluetooth/bluedroid/main/../btif/src/btif_dm.c line 1125 storing remote services failed (1) ###
10-31 10:24:09.219: E/BluetoothRemoteDevices(10778): devicePropertyChangedCallback: bdDevice: E0:C7:9D:64:99:27, value is empty for type: 3
```

Comment: What do you mean by "native" connection?

Comment: Go to Settings -> Bluetooth -> Find Devices -> Pair.